# HTML Border Appearing Outside of Cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uf23rtcs/

```css
table {
  margin: auto auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.borderless {
  border: none;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1, 1</td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="borderless"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="test">Cell 1, 3</td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="borderless"></td>
      <td>Cell 1, 6</td>
      <td>Cell 1, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 4</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 6</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Cell 2, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3, 1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 3, 4</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 4, 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now it's a fairly simple table, however, what I can't figure out is how to make the border of Cell 1, 3 not extend to the bottom because I need the space below Cell 3, 4 to be borderless.

The only solution I came up with is if I put in another borderless cell in that spot but I also need it to be devoid of any table data. How can I fix this?

It seems to also work somehow when I have the `border-collapse` set to separate (which is what I don't need).

Thank you.

Comment: this is because you have `rowspan` on both side.. try a different approach  to achieve it. thanks

Comment: Thank you! I got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use rowspan... If it's possible.

```css
table {
  margin: auto auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.borderless {
  border: none;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td colspan="2" class="test">Cell 1, 3</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td>Cell 1, 6</td>
      <td>Cell 1, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 4</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td>Cell 2, 6</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Cell 2, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 3, 4</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 4, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah thank you! So it's better to just manually add the gap column in each row then?

Comment: In that case you can add rowspans to second row after red-border-cell-row:

`<tr>
      <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
      <th rowspan="3" class="borderless"></th>
      <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 4</td>
      <th rowspan="3"  class="borderless"></th>
      <td>Cell 2, 6</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Cell 2, 7</td>
    </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```css
table {
  margin: auto auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.borderless {
  border: none;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th class="borderless" rowspan="10"></th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1, 1</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="test">Cell 1, 3</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td>Cell 1, 6</td>
      <td>Cell 1, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 4</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td>Cell 2, 6</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 2, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3, 1</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 3, 4</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>  
      <td>Cell 3, 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 4, 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the `border-collapse: collapse` rule.
With this rule adjacent table cells (`td` or `th`) share a border. With spanning cells (`cellspan` and `rowspan`) you can even have more than two cells sharing one border, i.e. there are two borders, which can be on top of each other.

Now there is a precedence, which cell's style and color is used on a particular border.
Among those are things like the style (solid beats dashed beats dotted), the border width (bigger width beats lower width) and the order of the cell in the HTML source code (the early cell beats the later cell)

This is the according specification from [CSS Level 2 (Tables)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution)

> The following rules determine which border style "wins" in case of a conflict:
>
> - Borders with the 'border-style' of 'hidden' take precedence over all other conflicting borders. Any border with this value suppresses all borders at this location.
> - Borders with a style of 'none' have the lowest priority. Only if the border properties of all the elements meeting at this edge are 'none' will the border be omitted (but note that 'none' is the default value for the border style.)
> - If none of the styles are 'hidden' and at least one of them is not 'none', then narrow borders are discarded in favor of wider ones. If several have the same 'border-width' then styles are preferred in this order: 'double', 'solid', 'dashed', 'dotted', 'ridge', 'outset', 'groove', and the lowest: 'inset'.
> - If border styles differ only in color, then a style set on a cell wins over one on a row, which wins over a row group, column, column group and, lastly, table. When two elements of the same type conflict, then the one further to the left (if the table's 'direction' is 'ltr'; right, if it is 'rtl') and further to the top wins.

This example illustrates some of the quirks of table borders.
There are two identical tables with the only difference being the `border-collapse` value.

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  padding: 10px;
}
table td.A, table td.F {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: magenta;
  border-width: 1px;
}
table td.B {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 5px;
}
table td.C {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 5px;
}
table td.H {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-top-color: black;
}
table td.I {
  border-color: green;
}
table td.D {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 5px;
}
table td.E {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>collapse</caption>
  <tr>
    <td class="A" rowspan="4">A</td>
    <td class="B">B</td>
    <td class="F" rowspan="4">F</td>
    <td class="G">G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="C">C</td>
    <td class="H">H</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="D">D</td>
    <td class="I">I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="E">E</td>
    <td class="J">J</td>
  </tr>
</table>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<table style="border-collapse: separate;">
  <caption>separate</caption>
  <tr>
    <td class="A" rowspan="4">A</td>
    <td class="B">B</td>
    <td class="F" rowspan="4">F</td>
    <td class="G">G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="C">C</td>
    <td class="H">H</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="D">D</td>
    <td class="I">I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="E">E</td>
    <td class="J">J</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to prevent your issue? Just do as [Daniil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11055546/daniil) [already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867830/476951). Don't use the spanning cells. This is easy, if you only have spanning empty cells, but what about spanning cells with content. This example shows:

```css
table {
  margin: auto auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.borderless {
  border: none;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td colspan="2">Cell 1, 3</td>
      <td class="borderless"></td>
      <td>Cell 1, 6</td>
      <td>Cell 1, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 4</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td class="test">Cell 2, 6</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Cell 2, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 3</td>
      <td>Cell 3, 4</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 3, 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 4, 1</td>
      <th class="borderless"></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case you need to refrain from using `border-collapse: collapse` and stick to `border-collapse: separate`, which leads to new issues, especially will you need to chose the 4 borders of every cell by hand.

```css
table {
  margin: auto auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

col.empty {
  border-width: 0;
  width: 10px;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  margin: -10px;
}

.bd-0-0-0-0,
.bd-1-0-0-0,
.bd-0-1-0-0,
.bd-1-1-0-0,
.bd-0-0-1-0,
.bd-1-0-1-0,
.bd-0-1-1-0,
.bd-1-1-1-0,
.bd-0-0-0-1,
.bd-1-0-0-1,
.bd-0-1-0-1,
.bd-1-1-0-1,
.bd-0-0-1-1,
.bd-1-0-1-1,
.bd-0-1-1-1,
.bd-1-1-1-1 {
  border: 0 solid black;
}

.bd-0-0-0-0 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-1-0-0-0 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-0-1-0-0 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-1-1-0-0 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 2;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-0-0-1-0 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-1-0-1-0 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-0-1-1-0 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-1-1-1-0 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.bd-0-0-0-1 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-1-0-0-1 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-0-1-0-1 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-1-1-0-1 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 2;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-0-0-1-1 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-1-0-1-1 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-0-1-1-1 {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.bd-1-1-1-1 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}


.test {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <cols>
    <col>
    <col class="empty">
    <col>
    <col>
    <col class="empty">
    <col>
    <col>
  </cols>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="bd-1-1-1-1">Header 1</th>
      <th class="bd-0-0-0-0"></th>
      <th class="bd-1-1-0-1">Header 2</th>
      <th class="bd-1-1-0-0">Header 3</th>
      <th class="bd-0-0-0-0"></th>
      <th class="bd-1-0-1-1">Header 4</th>
      <th class="bd-1-1-1-1">Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1">Cell 1, 1</td>
      <td class="bd-0-0-0-0" rowspan="4"></td>
      <td class="bd-1-1-1-1 test" colspan="2">Cell 1, 3</td>
      <td class="bd-0-0-0-0" rowspan="4"></td>
      <td class="bd-0-0-0-1">Cell 1, 6</td>
      <td class="bd-0-1-0-1">Cell 1, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1">Cell 2, 1</td>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1">Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-0">Cell 2, 4</td>
      <td class="bd-0-0-1-1 test">Cell 2, 6</td>
      <td class="bd-1-1-1-1" rowspan="4">Cell 2, 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1">Cell 3, 1</td>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1" rowspan="2">Cell 3, 3</td>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-0">Cell 3, 4</td>
      <td class="bd-0-0-1-1" rowspan="2">Cell 3, 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1">Cell 4, 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bd-0-1-1-1">Cell 5, 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```